# Given a SQL Express database base file (.MDF) how can I wipe/clear/reset the schema and/or data?

Tags: sql-server-express, mdf, sql-server-2008r2-express

Whats options do I have to clear the schema and data from a MDF file?  What options to delete all the data?

To reset a databases schema, it seems I need to copy a file from a backup of the database when it was empty.  I was wondering if there was a simpler or more efficient way.

To clear all data, it seems I'd need to write a script.  The script would disable constraints, then drop all rows from each table before turning back on constraints.  This is straightforward but does require I discover/track what tables exist in the database.  Maybe its not sufficient or there is an easier approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the point is of 'clearing the schema' - surely a new database already has a 'clear' schema.. BUT, you can create a new database in code via the following T-SQL:

```
USE Master
CREATE DATABASE NewDb (NAME=NewDbFile, FILENAME= '<filepath>')
```

If you need a file (an MDF) you can then detach the database too with [sp_detach_db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx) and you can then move it as required from the location specified above:

```
EXEC sp_detach_db NewDb
```

To clear the data you can use sp_msforeachtable with a truncation command - it is a non-logged operation, and does not check constraints, nor foreign keys - however, it **cannot** be rolled back!

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'
```

Comment: A new database would be great.  I need to do this programmatically though.  Can I create a MDF file via C#, SQL, powershell, or some other means besides the UI?

Comment: @Frank Schwieterman - you can create a database in SQL too - is this what you mean? I can modify the answer to suit..

Comment: Thanks I was able to get this working as I wanted with your help.